# Is there a way to get a list of all the parameters in protobufs in python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I want to write a script to fill protocol buffers values with the values given in a JSON file without knowing what is in the .proto file.

Comment: You cannot. Protobufs is a binary protocol which stores very little information about fields by design. In particular, it does not store names. It does store some basic information about types, though, so you probably can get _some_ data (a bunch of binary blobs and numbers with their tag numbers).

Comment: What about through the compiled protobuf python code?

Comment: What do you mean by "compiled"? If you already have a result of `protoc`, then you can plug that library in your code and use it, don't you?

Comment: I have been using the python file spit out by protoc, but it seems like you need to know the names of the variables, etc. I was wondering if there is a way to iterate through each field without knowing the names.

Comment: You can try loading a protobuf in an object like `my_proto` and then looking at result of `keys(my_proto)`, `dict(my_proto)`, `list(my_proto)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this example message here:

```
message MyMessage {
    int32 foo = 1;
}
```

You can get a list of the fields using `msg.DESCRIPTOR.fields`:

```
>>> msg = myproto_pb2.MyMessage()
>>> msg.DESCRIPTOR.fields
<MessageFields sequence>
>>> msg.DESCRIPTOR.fields[0].name
'foo'
```

But if your json format matches the .proto format, Google's protobuf library already provides a json parser:

```
>>> google.protobuf.json_format.Parse('{"foo":5}', msg)
```